# UISwitch with NSUserDefault

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I have a settings page in my app where I have a `UISwitch`. All I need is just to make the switch ON/OFF state to stay using `NSUserDefault`. Initailly my switch is OFF I get into settings turned ON when I get back to my main view and get into settings back the switch state gets back to OFF.

Here the code:

```
if ([indexPath row] == 4 && [indexPath section] == 0)//cellForRowAtIndexPath
    {

        UISwitch *myst =[[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 10, 30, 30)];
        [myst addTarget:self action:@selector(state:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myst];

    }


-(IBAction)state:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (sender.tag == 0) {
        if (sender.on ==1) {
            [standardDefaults setObject:@"On" forKey:@"val"];

        }
    }else if(sender.on == 0){

        [standardDefaults setObject:@"Off" forKey:@"val"];
    }

    [standardDefaults synchronize];


}
```

IN viewWillAppear :

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([[standardDefaults stringForKey:@"val"]isEqualToString:@"On"]) {

        myst.on=YES;
    }else if ([[standardDefaults stringForKey:@"val"]isEqualToString:@"Off"]){

        myst.on=NO;
    }
```

I need to make the state i.e if user turns ON it should be ON state even after switching views or stop and run back the app. How to make this state persist?

Answer (score 3):

You are **not** setting the state of UISwitch in **UITableview's cellForRowAtIndexPath** method where it is created.

In you Tableview you have to set switch state,

**Edit**

```
if ([indexPath row] == 4 && [indexPath section] == 0)//cellForRowAtIndexPath
{

    UISwitch *myst =[[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 10, 30, 30)];
    [myst addTarget:self action:@selector(state:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

// You have to set your older state of UISwitch here. 

      NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     if ([[standardDefaults stringForKey:@"val"]isEqualToString:@"On"]) {

        myst.on=YES;
     }else if ([[standardDefaults stringForKey:@"val"]isEqualToString:@"Off"]){

        myst.on=NO;
     }
    [cell.contentView addSubview:myst];

}
```

Comment: you mean initial state as "myst.on=NO;" Is that right?

Comment: No,State which you have stored in NSuserDefault.

Comment: What ever the state is you have to set it from userDefaults.Check Edited answer.

Comment: Set Initially OFF for `val` in AppDelegate with NSUserDefaults's `registerDefaults` method.

Comment: Thanks .. but it does not works.When I get back and get into settings state changes back.